# GitHub rate_limit api shows that core has only 60 api limit for authenticated user

Tags: github, github-api

GitHub rate_limit api shows that core has only 60 api limit for one authenticated user. I am using personal access token and it is showing 60 as rate limit. Is there configuration where I cehck why it is showing 60 and not 5000.

I tried checking in user settings but could not find anything there.

The pat has access to all.
i am trying to hit the workflow list api.

Comment: Please edit your question to mention what scopes you have on your personal access token and what API endpoints you're trying to access.  You aren't properly authenticated or you don't have the proper scopes if your rate limit is 60.

Comment: @arnab Did you figure this out? I'm facing the same issue. I have 2 accounts. One account shows 5000 as it should, and the other only 60 per hour. Both have the same token permissions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make unauthenticated requests if you are only fetching public data. Unauthenticated requests are associated with the originating IP address, not with the user or application that made the request.

The primary rate limit for unauthenticated requests is 60 requests per hour.

You can use a personal access token to make API requests. Additionally, you can authorize a GitHub App or OAuth app, which can then make API requests on your behalf.

All of these requests count towards your personal rate limit of 5,000 requests per hour. Requests made on your behalf by a GitHub App that is owned by a GitHub Enterprise Cloud organization have a higher rate limit of 15,000 requests per hour. Similarly, requests made on your behalf by a OAuth app that is owned or approved by a GitHub Enterprise Cloud organization have a higher rate limit of 15,000 requests per hour if you are a member of the GitHub Enterprise Cloud organization.

GitHub Apps authenticating with an installation access token use the installation's minimum rate limit of 5,000 requests per hour. If the installation is on a GitHub Enterprise Cloud organization, the installation has a rate limit of 15,000 requests per hour.

Hope this answers your question.

Source: [Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/rate-limits-for-the-rest-api)